# What’s is the consequence of trimming too much of a wood door?

Tags: wood, doors, woodworking, door-frame, fitting

I’d like to have all matching doors downstairs in our house ([link](https://www.diy.com/departments/2-panel-knotty-pine-internal-door-h-1981mm-w-838mm/3663602691426_BQ.prd)), but one of our door frames is shorter than all the others. The doors say the maximum you can trim off any given side is 5 mm, but I need to trim 12 mm off both top and bottom to get this particular one to fit. To my knowledge, this door only comes in one size.

What would be the consequence of trimming the extra 7 mm be and is there anything I can do to mitigate it?

[image: Photo of top of the door]

Comment: Side may not be the same as ends.

Comment: Do you know if there's empty space above the door that is covered by the molding? You may be able to remove the framing and "raise" it for more clearance, but you'd have to do that to six framing pieces and it may be more work than you'd want to perform.

Comment: @fred_dot_u it’s a hollow stud wall so modifying or replacing the frame is an option, just not my first one

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your picture (wild guess) you have 35 mm on both sides. 12 mm should do nothing to the structural integrity of your door. More picture and measurement would be always helpful.